# Generic Web Service Method Using Key Value Pairs

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, wcf, wsdl

We have a legacy application with a very large and varied set of stored procedures used to interact with the database.  We're exposing a specific sub-set of these functions via a new Web Services layer that we'll publish to 3rd parties.

Should we write a single generic web service, or to write a service and methods for each function to be exposed?

#### Option 1

A single web service and WSDL that takes as its parameters an API name and list of key/value pairs.  The service would use the API name provided to look-up the stored proc in question and then map the key/value pairs to the proc.   This design intended to (a) reduce the web service code to be written and (b) reduce later cost as and when requests to expose other stored procs are received.

#### Option 2

We generate a WSDL and service for each function and sproc to be exposed, and name them specifically.  E.g. Client.wsdl with methods AddClient, UpdateClient, DeleteClient and User.wsdl with methods AddUser, ReportUser, UpdateUser, etc.  This design intended to make life easier for 3rd parties building to the interface and to allow for validation specific to each method to be moved into the service tier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with Option 2

Web services are quite an overhead for your application (versus just TCP connections with a custom binary protocol).  Their entire purpose is to produce simple interfaces that 3rd parties can use easily.

You also touched on another important point. If you use key/value pairs you loose a lot of validation. You will probably get calls that go, "We tried to use your API and its just not working!!". So by publishing a more detailed WSDL file its easier to track who is "at fault" if the communication doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a from-scratch build, we would go with Option 2 also, following @Paul's advice.

However, after detailed planning & estimation, we've come to the conclusion that Option 1 (a single method offering key/value pairs) is preferable for our provide-access-to-a-legacy-API situation.

This was because:

1. we have a large number of stored procs to which we will need to provide access
2. while we're providing a new way of accessing it, the application's architecture is still based around these stored procs and the tables upon which they operate - e.g. as the app is extended, it will initial be at this tier
3. development of a generic web service method greatly reduces the incremental cost of exposing each stored process

It means we reduce future software change cost at the risk of increased API support calls, but expect to mitigate this with very comprehensive documentation for our users.